# Est-ce que « depuis tantôt » est une expression idiomatique ?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

Il y a dans la préface du roman *Notre-Dame de Paris* la phrase suivante :

> Car c’est ainsi qu’on agit *depuis tantôt* deux cents ans avec les
>   merveilleuses églises du moyen-âge.

Ce que je voudrais savoir, c'est s'il s'agit d'une expression idiomatique. Je me le demande car la combinaison des mots *depuis tantôt* me semble intraduisible.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! Good question. I can't even begin to guess what this sentence means. *On agit* and *depuis tantôt* both seem ambiguous.

Comment: @Aerovistae Thanks. Indeed they are. Hence my question in the first place. I know that "tantôt" is a synonym of "bientôt," which of course means "soon," but when you put this word together with "depuis ... deux cents ans," which translates as "for two centuries," the combination thereof doesn't seem, at least to me, to make a lot of sense.

Comment: Actually I can guess: The preceding sentence describes an inscription being painted over or scraped away, so this might mean *And so it is that we've behaved for the past 200 years towards the marvelous churches of the Middles Ages.* If I am right, *depuis tantôt deux cents ans* is something like *since 200 years earlier.* But worry not, some expert will waltz in and give a definitive answer before morning.

Comment: And *bientôt* might be a synonym of *tantôt* in some contexts, but I am inclined to think this is not one of them. I think it means *earlier* here, not *soon*.

Comment: @Aerovistae You may be right. However, "tantôt" as "early" is nowhere recorded as such; as far as I know, of course.

Comment: I informed the guess from the "examples and translations in context" section of [Reverso's page on the word](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/tantot), as well as Wiktionnaire's [second definition](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tant%C3%B4t) -- "peu de temps avant ou après, tout à l'heure, jusqu'à maintenant." But I am just as eager as you for someone else's insight.

Comment: @Aerovistae So am I... So am I...

Comment: *Depuis bientôt deux cents ans* is idiomatic. *Tantôt* is an outdated synonym here.

Comment: @Aerovistae: that's what we've been doing (rather than *behave* here).

Comment: @jlliagre An outdated synonym of what?

Comment: An outdated synonym of *bientôt* when used with this meaning.

Comment: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tant%C3%B4t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> depuis **tantôt** deux cents ans

=

> depuis **bientôt** deux cents ans

=

> depuis **presque** deux cents ans

That leads you to:

> for **nearly** 200 years

Comment: Does "tantôt" also mean "presque"? Would you be so kind as to indicate the source for this? As a philologist, I really need to be mathematically exact when it comes to the meanings of words. Thank you.

Comment: @user26328 Hi. No, it's not that "tantôt/bientôt" has the meaning of "almost". But the idea that "it will soon{tantôt} be 200 years" in English is virtually the same by interpretation as "it is almost{presque} 200 years". Incidentally, "tantôt" is outdated, compared to "bientôt".

Comment: As previousluy stated *tantôt* is here a synonym of *bientôt*.  Let's do it on a more usual expression. *Il est bientôt cinq heures* → It'll soon be five" , so far I expect we agree. Wouldn't you say that "it'll soon be five" means the same as"it's nearly five" ? I would definitely translate *c’est ainsi qu’on agit depuis tantôt deux cents ans* by "that's what we've been doing for nearly 200 years". Words are not context free and *nearly* is an appropriate translation in this context, it would not work in any context.

Comment: @Laure Oui, c'est très clair maintenant. Merci beaucoup. J'ai tout compris depuis tantôt quelque secondes...

Comment: @user26328 you should accept an answer and make a full-time account to join FL.stackexchange for real!

Comment: @Aerovistae I am afraid I don't understand your last message.

Comment: The way stack exchange works is the person who asked the question is able to mark an answer as 'Accepted' by clicking the checkmark next to it, which floats the answer to the top. The idea is that you do this for the answer you deem the most helpful. Other than that I was just recommending you make a real account, since this site is amazing but needs more users. I can tell by your name "user26328" that you're an anonymous user. Although maybe you prefer it that way :)

Comment: Yes, but he didn't choose the username "user26328," that's an auto-assigned thing. I had assumed that was for users who hadn't fully registered. How do you get assigned a name like that?

Comment: @Aerovistae According to [this apparently abominable question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281260/i-have-a-perhaps-irrational-fear-that-brand-new-users-with-auto-generated-user), you can leave the name field blank to trigger that generation.

Answer (score 3):

> depuis **tantôt** deux cents ans = depuis **bientôt** deux cents ans
>
> "it will ***soon*** be 200 years" = "it is ***almost*** 200 years"

The "tantôt/bientôt" is inserted here to express the idea of "approaching 200 years", as opposed to simply saying "depuis deux cents ans" that denotes "it has already reached the mark of 200 years".